# Why is my bootstrap toggler not toggling?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have followed the instructions and included the javascript packages into my file. However, whenever I click the toggle button, it does not toggle at all, why is that so? Does it have something to do with the version of my packages?

I have included some Django templating syntax, do ignore those

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'investing/layout.css' %}" />
        {% block script %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggle-label">Menu</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">(toggle)</span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item mt-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Features
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fundamental Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex ml-5">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success ml-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using bootstrap 5 syntax `data-bs-toggle`

but you using bootstrap 4 change `data-bs-toggle` to `data-toggle`

Check out the bootstrap 4 documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'investing/layout.css' %}" />
        {% block script %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggle-label">Menu</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">(toggle)</span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item mt-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Features
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fundamental Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex ml-5">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success ml-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for identifying the problem! I changed it to bootstrap5        

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">`

and replaced the script tags at the bottom with bootstrap5 bundle instead

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`